# Spark + Mesos cluster mode, who uploads the jar?

Tags: apache-spark, mesos

I'm trying to run Spark applications with Mesos cluster mode. (I've got client mode working but still would like to try cluster mode)

I have launched `spark-mesos-dispatcher` on the Mesos master node.

When I submit the assembly at local path `/tmp/assembly.jar` using the following command,

```
bin/spark-submit --master mesos://dispatcher:7077 --deploy-mode cluster --class com.example.Example /tmp/assembly.jar
```

It fails because the file `/tmp/assembly.jar` does not exist on the mesos slave nodes.

```
I1129 10:47:43.839771  5884 fetcher.cpp:414] Fetcher Info: {"cache_directory":"\/tmp\/mesos\/fetch\/slaves\/9d725348-931a-48fb-96f7-d29a4b09f3e8-S9\/deploy","items":[{"action":"BYPASS_CACHE","uri":{"extract":true,"value":"\/tmp\/assembly.jar"}}],"sandbox_directory":"\/var\/lib\/mesos\/slaves\/9d725348-931a-48fb-96f7-d29a4b09f3e8-S9\/frameworks\/9d725348-931a-48fb-96f7-d29a4b09f3e8-0291\/executors\/driver-20151129104742-0008\/runs\/31bf5840-226e-4b87-ae76-d14bd2f17950","user":"user"}
I1129 10:47:43.840710  5884 fetcher.cpp:369] Fetching URI '/tmp/assembly.jar'
I1129 10:47:43.840721  5884 fetcher.cpp:243] Fetching directly into the sandbox directory
I1129 10:47:43.840731  5884 fetcher.cpp:180] Fetching URI '/tmp/assembly.jar'
I1129 10:47:43.840737  5884 fetcher.cpp:160] Copying resource with command:cp '/tmp/assembly.jar' '/var/lib/mesos/slaves/9d725348-931a-48fb-96f7-d29a4b09f3e8-S9/frameworks/9d725348-931a-48fb-96f7-d29a4b09f3e8-0291/executors/driver-20151129104742-0008/runs/31bf5840-226e-4b87-ae76-d14bd2f17950/assembly.jar'
cp: cannot stat `/tmp/assembly.jar': No such file or directory
Failed to fetch '/tmp/assembly.jar': Failed to copy with command 'cp '/tmp/assembly.jar' '/var/lib/mesos/slaves/9d725348-931a-48fb-96f7-d29a4b09f3e8-S9/frameworks/9d725348-931a-48fb-96f7-d29a4b09f3e8-0291/executors/driver-20151129104742-0008/runs/31bf5840-226e-4b87-ae76-d14bd2f17950/assembly.jar'', exit status: 256
Failed to synchronize with slave (it's probably exited)
```

In case of YARN cluster mode, [Spark's YARN client implementation will upload the application jar to HDFS so that the driver and all executors have access to the jar](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v1.5.2/yarn/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/deploy/yarn/Client.scala#L227-L253), but I could not find such code in [RestSubmissionClient](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v1.5.2/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/deploy/rest/RestSubmissionClient.scala), which is used by Mesos or Standalond cluster mode.

Who does the uploading in this case? or do I need to manually put the application assembly somewhere accessible via an HTTP URI?

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding you could use the [SparkContext](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.SparkContext) `addJar()` method to add a local (to the driver application) JAR file path, which will then be distributed to the executor nodes (in client mode).

As you state that you want to use cluster mode, I'd suggest that you have a look at the [Spark Jobserver](https://github.com/spark-jobserver/spark-jobserver) project, which should make the running of Spark applications on Mesos easier than with the built-in tools.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions but I know what those do, and you didn't answer my question. I should send this question to the spark-user mailing list.